# Implement Fill in the blanks using drag & drop jQuery in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

I am implementing a ***Fill in the blanks*** drag & drop functionality.

[image]

[**Codepen Link**](https://codepen.io/bhuwanb9/pen/LemoeO)

Here I have a list of answers above i.e. ***one, two, three, etc.*** and empty spaces below where these answers will be filled.

***Things which is done***

**1)** Drag the options from answers list and fill in the empty boxes. ***Done***

**2)** If I drag a answer from a filled box to an empty box, previous value should be blank. ***Done***

***Now comes the Issue***

***1)*** If I drag a answer from a filled box to an another filled box then how to switch the values and position of both the boxes. I have thought that we can get the position of the previous one and current one and then swap the position but don't know how to implement it.

***2)*** If I drag a value from answers list to a filled box then how to swap them

Here what I have done so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var arr;
  $("span").droppable({
    accept: "ul > li",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      arr = [];
      var dragedElement = ui.draggable.text();
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      $(this).html(dragedElement);
      $('span').each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).text());
      });
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(arr));

      var matched = arr.filter((value) => value == dragedElement);
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(matched));

      $('span').each(function() {
        if ($(this).text() == matched[1]) {
          $(this).addClass('matched');
          //localStorage.setItem('prevValue', $(this).text());
          $('span.matched').text('');
          $(this).removeClass("ui-state-highlight");
          $(this).removeClass('matched');
        }
      });

      $(this).html(dragedElement);
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");

    }
  });

  $("ul > li").draggable({
    revert: "invalid"
  });
})
```

```css
span {
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 20px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

body {
  font: 13px Verdana;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
  background: yellow;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgb(0, 255, 213);
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgb(255, 145, 0);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
</ul>
<p>hello
  <span></span>hello
  <span></span>hello
  <span></span>
</p>
```

Comment: First, determine where an answer (green) has been dragged from, for example by recording it on mouse down. Then handle some cases...

Comment: I don't think making `ui li` droppable is a good idea. Also making `ui li` and `ui > li` consistent would be better - they have different meaning, depends on the circumstances.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you don't need to drag filled answer to another answer because users have multiple options and can drag every option to answer and when user do it answer modifies by latest option. It's make no sense user drags option after drop to answer. For doing this scenario you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("span").droppable({
    accept: "ul > li",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      var dragedElement = ui.draggable.text();
      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      $(this).html(dragedElement);
      $(this).addClass('matched');  
    }
  });

  $("ul li").draggable({
    helper:"clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  });

})
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/h7dusx03/)

**Edit**

If you want to drag answers you can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // This code used for set order attribute for options
var numberOfItems = $("#options").find('li').length;
$.each($("#options").find('li'), function(index, item) {
    $(item).attr("order", index);
    var removeBotton = $('<i class="fa fa-times" style="display:none"></i>');
    removeBotton.click(function(){
        addToOlderPlace($(this).parent());        
      });
    $(item).append(removeBotton);

});

  $("span").droppable({
    accept: "li",
    classes: {
      "ui-droppable-hover": "ui-state-hover"
    },
    drop: function(event, ui) {
    // Check for existing another option
    if($(this).find('li').length > 0)
    addToOlderPlace($(this).find('li'));

      $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
      $(this).addClass('matched');  

      $(ui.draggable).find('i').attr("style","");
      $(this).append($(ui.draggable));    

    }
  });

  $("li").draggable({
    helper:"clone",
    revert: "invalid"
  }); 


  // This function used for find old place of option
  // This function used for find old place of item


  function addToOlderPlace($item) {
        var indexItem = $item.attr('order');
        var itemList = $("#options").find('li');
        $item.find('i').hide();         

        if (indexItem === "0")
            $("#options").prepend($item);
        else if (Number(indexItem) === (Number(numberOfItems)-1))        
               $("#options").append($item);                       
        else
            $(itemList[indexItem - 1]).after($item);
    }

})
```

[**Online demo (jsFiddle)**](https://jsfiddle.net/ali_soltani/6yo9djcb/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the response! But I am looking for a solution in which I can drag a filled answer to another. And one answer can only be used once in the boxes but in your answer an answer is used multiple times.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt I added new code to my answer for allowing drag answers. Please see it again. I hope it helps you.

Comment: I tried your solution1, its working good but at some point its being stopped to replace the text.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt I don't implement replace text of element after drop because you can get text from draggable element (option) that drop to answer. I think you don't need to replace text.

Comment: I tried your 2nd solution. This issue is coming sometimes https://imgur.com/a/CmY5O. I like the idea of replacing the text, but can you tell me why this issue is coming

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt I fixed 2nd solution please see it again. I know how we can replace the text but I still think it's better to work with `option` and get text from it.

Comment: @BhuwanBhatt Did you test my solution after latest edit? Do you need more explanations?

Answer (score 1):

I made a fiddle some time ago to demonstrate how to solve a problem of this type. Including `tolerance:intersect` in the drop/droppable functions is key to the solution.

In this snippet, I have not imitated your code, but provided the example from my fiddle so that you can see how you can apply this solution to your own code.

```js
$("#launchPad").height($(window).height() - 20);
var dropSpace = $(window).width() - $("#launchPad").width();
$("#dropZone").width(dropSpace - 70);
$("#dropZone").height($("#launchPad").height());

$(".card").draggable({
    appendTo: "#launchPad",
    cursor: "move",
    helper: 'clone',
    revert: "invalid",

});

$("#launchPad").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        $("#launchPad").append($(ui.draggable));
    }
});

$(".stackDrop1").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
    }
});

$(".stackDrop2").droppable({
    tolerance: "intersect",
    accept: ".card",
    activeClass: "ui-state-default",
    hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
    drop: function(event, ui) {        
        $(this).append($(ui.draggable));
    }
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

#launchPad {
  width: 200px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

#dropZone {
  float: right;
  border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
  background-color: #ffffcc;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #eaeaea;
}

.stack {
  width: 180px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  margin: 20px;
}

.stackHdr {
  background-color: #eaeaea;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  padding: 5px
}

.stackDrop1,
.stackDrop2 {
  min-height: 100px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div id="launchPad">
  <div class="card draggable">
    apple
  </div>
  <div class="card draggable">
    orange
  </div>
  <div class="card draggable">
    banana
  </div>
  <div class="card draggable">
    car
  </div>
  <div class="card draggable">
    bus
  </div>
</div>

<div id="dropZone">
  <div class="stack">
    <div class="stackHdr">
      Drop here
    </div>
    <div class="stackDrop1 droppable">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="stack">
    <div class="stackHdr">
      Or here
    </div>
    <div class="stackDrop2 droppable">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/wL6ppxw4/) also

Hope this helps